# CRM 2016 Error report screen being shown to users

Tags: access-denied, error-reporting, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm using Dynamics CRM 2016 (on prem). When a user browses to an entity form they don't have privileges to read I get the screen below. The screen says CRM error report, AccessCheckEx failed. And it has a full stack trace.

[image: CRM Error Report]

In CRM 2011 I was getting the more user friendly Access Denied screen. Is this configurable? I don't want users seeing the error report screen as it's too verbose. The access denied screen would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `DevErrors` is set:

On the CRM frontend server (if you have more than one be sure you do this on each of them) open the [CRMSERVER]\web.config (i.e., \Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb\web.config) file.

Modify the `DevErrors` line to read:

`<add key="DevErrors" value="Off"/>`

You'll need to have opened your editor as Administrator (or save locally and then update the file) as the folder should be restricted to updates by the Administrator only.

Usually IIS will see the web.config has changed but if it does not automatically take then execute `iisreset` on each server.

Comment: Out of curiosity, was this setting somehow updated on the OP's system? Because I think it is set to be off by default?

Comment: Thanks dude, you rock! Not sure how it was ever set to On to be honest, I didn't do the install.

Comment: This has fixed my problem, but testers being as they are are complaining the Access denied dialog box isn't closing when you click the close button. I'm not getting any client side js errors on the click event, just doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. I would post as a new question with a screenshot.